# Проверка массива

Tags: php

Имеется массив: Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 1 )
Необходимо проверить, есть ли в массиве значение больше нуля. Каким способом это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Больше плохого кода! Выражение возвращает `TRUE`, если в массиве `$a` есть положительные элементы.

```
$result = array_reduce( $a, function( $r, $e){ return $r || $e > 0;}, FALSE);
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/a2125T)

Comment: Ничем не отличается от прохода массива циклом.

Comment: повышает осведомлённость читателей о нативных ф-ях для работы с массивами.

Comment: Да, только не все наитивные функции работают быстрее. Пример https://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-exists.php
Хорошо, что я в свое время я почитал комменты по функциям, отказался от некоторых наитивных в пользу других самописных решений - работает быстрее.

Comment: Для примера ОП с тремя элементами в массиве оптимизация кхм.

И да, я не зря написал про плохой код: этот вариант, как и `max()` просматривает все элементы. Поэтому предпочтительнее цикл+break.

Comment: Когда  массив >25к записей (и каждая запись это массив) - то экономия времени примерно на секунд 30- разница офигенная.

Comment: Скажу по секрету, что массивов на 25к быть просто не должно, нужно уже итераторами работать.

Comment: Скажу по секрету, СЕЙЧАС уже ГЕНЕРАТОРЫ, а итераторы в прошлом.  
А массив в 25к записей - может быть спокойно)  
Да еще тайну, наверно, для вас открою - конструкции for, foreach - являются неявными итераторами.

Comment: @Ale_x скажу по секрету, что я не имел в виду конкретный паттерн PHP, а принцип работы с миддл дата вообще, обработку данных по одной сущности - строке, xml-тегу, записи в БД.

Answer (score 2):

Обычным, for, foreach, каким угодно.

Comment: И маленький примерчик к вашему ответу http://ideone.com/pRY8wA

Comment: @mountpoint nope http://ideone.com/YH5Ijd

Comment: @Etki, про*бался, бывает http://ideone.com/5V73RT

Answer (score 1):

max(array(2, 4, 5)) - вернет максимальный элемент.

Если он больше нуля, то значит в массивы есть элементы >0.

Единственное: проработай вариант, когда есть 2 максим. элемента - тогда max(array()) вернет массив элементов.